# jQuery Mobile not responding to, or not triggering, taps on HTML5 iPhone app (Safari)

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, html, jquery-mobile

We're using jQuery Mobile to handle gestures and touch events for a iPhone HTML5 web app. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work after a few taps. We're using JQM 1.3.2, the latest stable, along with jQuery 1.10.1.

To reproduce:

1) Visit [www.tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com) on an iPhone or www.tekiki.com/dandy/dandy from a desktop.

2) Swipe left to show the category menu.

3) Tap on the **Games** category (not **All Games**).

4) After the games render, tap on the **Finance** category.

At this point, taps on other categories are ignored. It doesn't seem like JQM is triggering the **tap** event since breakpoints in the relevant code below aren't getting hit.

Code snippet:

```
// Bind what happens when user taps on category
$( '#templates .category_box' ).on( 'tap', function( ev ) {     
    // Prevent double taps
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Set category picked history
    CHOSEN_CATEGORY_ID = $(this).attr('itunes_id');

    // Show page
    p_change_page( '#category_page' );
});
```

Comment: try `vclick` instead. are you appending any items dynamically? if yes, use this `$(document).on('tap',  '#templates .category_box', function( ev ) {`

Comment: @Omar, could you post your comment as an answer? It worked (with some modification) but why did we need this? We bound the event to a template then deep copied the template (including events) when creating dynamic elements. Shouldn't deep copying a template element that is already bound to the tap event work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements should be present in DOM when binding events to them. Even copied / cloned elements are considered dynamic, and the way of binding events to them

```
$(document).on('event', '.dynamic', function () {
 // code
});
```

Or this way

```
$('.static_parent').on('event', '.dynamic', function () {
 // code
});
```

Comment: thanks, @omar. any clue why the original approach failed? according to the docs, cloning with true as a parameter should copy the events from the template item. if this works, isn't this a more efficient approach because JQM only needs to deep copy events and doesn't need to watch for dynamic elements? http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @Crashalot I assume it depends on page event (pageinit, pageshow, pagebeforeshow etc...) you bind other events. Put an alert or a console log and see if it fires twice with my fix above, and bind them to any page event.

Comment: your fix definitely works (with a minor modification), just curious why our original approach failed. the confusing part is that it works for a few taps (even after dynamic creation of elements) then fails.

Comment: @Crashalot does it fail on the same cloned element or different ones after several taps? When tapping, do you clone the tapped element?

Comment: nope, we don't clone the tapped element on tap. only when creating the elements the first time. all the categories are cloned versions of the same template.

Comment: @Crashalot when cloning, you append the cloned elements to the same page or you migrate them to a different one?